# getCurrentSession returns null when creating a Session

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, nullpointerexception

I'm  getting a `nullPointerException`  when deploying my  `Maven Web Application  JSF-2.2 +Hibernate`:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host]
.[/maven-project].[FacesServlet]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)
 JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ubosque.mb.CiudadanoMB.getAllCiudadanos(CiudadanoMB.java:28)
 [classes:]
```

When I take a look at  `com.ubosque.mb.CiudadanoMB.getAllCiudadanos(CiudadanoMB.java:28)`
This  is the   line that comes up:

```
sesion = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

HibernateSessionFactory  class:

```
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = setSessionFactory();

private  static SessionFactory setSessionFactory() {

    try {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {  //  if  session  == null 
            Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder regbuild = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            StandardServiceRegistry builder = regbuild.applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(builder);
         }//  if session  == null                               
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// try - catch
    return sessionFactory;
}// setSessionFactory

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Cannot  seem to find what  my problem  is, I'm just learning about `Hibernate`. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = setSessionFactory();
```

This line, for some reason, fails, and keeps sessionFactory as null. This happens before your NPE is thrown, obviously, which causes `HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()` to return null, which in turn causes your NPE, so I would recommend going through your output and checking what stack trace the `setSessionFactory` prints to your standard output.

Also, this way of instantiating the session factory is dirty - you have no certainty of whether it actually is instantiated. That exception probably shouldn't be caught there, but should throw an IllegalStateException (most likely) with the original exception as cause:

```
try {
    // ...                         
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}// try - catch
```

This way if your application crashes, you actually have a way of at least knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call method `getCurrentSession()`, hibernate means that instance of session is already created. But it is not true (it is null and as a result it throw NullPointerEx). First of all you must create session with method `openSession()`, and after that you can call method `getCurrentSession()`.